# Bar plot coming out distorted, how can I resolve this problem?

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart

Trying to create a simple bar graph with x-axis being id number, y-axis being read counts. However, when I use the command `df.plot.bar()` the plot comes out distorted with multiple bars, should not have multiple bars grouped together.

Output: [image]

What I expected:[image]

Example table:

| cell id | read counts |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1350 |
| 2 | 2000 |
| 3 | 1350 |
| 4 | 50000 |
| 5 | 3300 |
| 6 | 4000 |
| 7 | 2100 |
| 8 | 20000 |

Note: the data is much larger size

is .plot.bar() not the right command to make the bar graph for my interest?
Histogram is not the plot I'm looking for (already made one)

Actual dataframe:

[image]

Comment: when you plot the example data that you provided do you see the problem? If so can you show the problem chart?

Comment: @ChrisSeeling not but the example table is much much smaller size than the actual dataframe (4340 rows x 2 col). When I do the example table it does not have any problem. I will post the chart in the post

Comment: @ChrisSeeling posted the chart

Comment: reduce your data frame row count to the minimum size that exhibits the problem, like df.loc[:5,:]  then try reposting that, also to plot what is your code? e.g. I used df.loc[:5,:].plot.bar('id','count')

Comment: @ChrisSeeling i just used df.plot.bar() shown in the first picture. If I do df.loc[:300,:].plot.bar('cell id', 'count') it starts to look distorted.

Comment: try plotting your ids only: df['id'].plot()   -  do you see the ids increasing uniformly as you expect.

Comment: @ChrisSeeling says 'no numeric data to plot'

Answer (score 1):

Try this an compare with your code. Hope this helps in identifying the issue.

```
import pandas as pd
Y = [1350,2000,1350,50000,3300,4000,2100,20000,1000]
X = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','20']

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.bar(X,Y)

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(X, Y)), columns=['id','count'])
```

Comment: Looks better less spacing between bars https://imgur.com/a/jaXlyp4 but missing some high peaks e.g. there should be one bar that peaks to 50,000 and couple at 2-30,000 when I tried the code